# Get name of folder within glob method

Tags: php

I'm iterating with glob through my image-folder with nested folders to find images. The structure looks like this:

```
-> images
   -> John Doe (some names)
     -> 21-09-2018 (some dates)
     -> 23-09-2018 (some dates)
```

Now I would like to get the name of 'name'-folder and the name of the 'date'-folder in which the image is. How can I get these in my existing loop and push it to my array?

```
$fileArray = [];
$path = 'http://example.com/demo';

foreach (glob("images/*/*/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}", GLOB_BRACE) as $curFilename)
{
$completePath = $path . '/' . $curFilename;

$FilenameWithoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', basename($curFilename));

$basename = basename($curFilename);

if (strpos($FilenameWithoutExt, 'R') !== false) {
    $eye = 'R';
}
else if (strpos($FilenameWithoutExt, 'L') !== false) {
    $eye = 'L';
} else {
    $eye = '';
}

$caption =  $eye . ' - ' . date("d.m.Y");

$curFileObj = new mFile;
$curFileObj->caption = $caption;
$curFileObj->url = $completePath;
$curFileObj->thumbUrl = $completePath;  
$curFileObj->date = date("d.m.Y");
$curFileObj->eye = $eye;
$curFileObj->basename = $basename;
array_push($fileArray, $curFileObj);
}
echo json_encode($fileArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SplFileInfo**

You can just make a `SplFileInfo` object from file pathname.

For example:

```
$file = new SplFileInfo($curFilename);
echo $file->getPath();
```

will output path to your file.

There is more methods you can use, and I think you should find everything you need inside this object.

**RecursiveIteratorIterator**

There is also something like `RecursiveIteratorIterator` which will return array of `SplFileInfo` instead of just string pathnames like `glob()` does.

You can use it like:

```
$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('images/*/*/');
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

But inside you have to check extension if it is what you expect.

---

**Manual**

[The SplFileInfo class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)

[The RecursiveIteratorIterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)